# How can I count the number of one Number in a list

Tags: python

I need to know, in Python, how can I count the number of a number in a list, for example :

```py
l = [0,1,2,5,6,5,0,0,0]
```

if the zone is 3:

the maximum number of zeros in a zone of three numbers is three (at the end)

(it must count like that : 0;1;2: one zero, 1;2;5 no zero, 2;5;6 no zero...)

(the goal of the exercise is to print the highest number of zeros in a zone determined by int(input()) in a list of numbers)

Thank you for the help!

It is for my school homework, in mathematics, we do exercises in Python

Comment: school homeworks are not entertained here unless you show your genuine efforts in solving the problem

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have list called `l` and you have to decleare your zone, it might change.
Also I added `search_number` variable if you want to search other than `0`

```
l = [0,1,2,5,6,5,0,0,0]
zone = 3
search_number = 0
```

Now you should seperate your list into clusters

```
clusterlist = []
for index in range(l.__len__()):
    clusterlist.append(l[index:zone+index])
```

You have cluster list like `0,1,2`,`1,2,5`. `max_cluster_have_zeros` will save count of maximum zeros are in your cluster. `save_cluster` will store your cluster which includes maximum zeros.

```
save_cluster = None
max_cluster_have_zeros = 0
for cluster in clusterlist:
    cluster_have_zeros = cluster.count(search_number)
    if (max_cluster_have_zeros < cluster_have_zeros):
        max_cluster_have_zeros = cluster_have_zeros
        save_cluster = cluster
```

Comment: `l.__len__()` : dundermethods are not supposed to be called - use `len(l)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
L = [0,1,2,5,6,5,0,0,0]
print([x.count(0) for x in zip(L,L[1:],L[2:])])
```

As a more generic solution, for a variable value and a variable zone-size, you can use this:

```
def getCount(arr,val,zone):
    z = [arr[n:] for n in range(zone)]
    return [x.count(val) for x in zip(*z)]
```

Then, for example, you can do:

```
countArr = getCount(arr=[0,1,2,5,6,5,0,0,0],val=0,zone=3)
print(countArr)
print(max(countArr))
```

Comment: I guess you misunderstand the question

Comment: @ÖmrümÇetin: To my understanding, the goal is to print the number of zeros in each (sliding) window of 3 consecutive items. Of course, if the max of those is required, then you can simply `print(max([x.count(0) for x in zip(L,L[1:],L[2:])]))`. I wasn't sure which of these two options is the desired one, so I referred to the first option, assuming that this dude could easily derive from it a solution to the second option.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: what if he want to put zone as 4? This may only respond for 3. And you should carry your comment to question to be more clear.

Comment: @ÖmrümÇetin: OK, I added a more general solution.